# Why my Disabled product collection gives empty array in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, product-collection, magento2.3.5-p1, disabled-products

I want to get disabled product id's in my system but it gives me an empty array.

Here is screenshot of my products.When i grab disabled product by using this code

```
$updatedproids = [];
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
    $productCollection;

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $updatedproids[] = $product->getId();
    }
print_r($updatedproids);
```

I think there should be an issue with Magento Saleable Quantity but i'm not sure why i didn't get this.

Comment: If you are using MSI I don't think this has_stock_status_filter flag works. You should join with MSI tables.

Comment: How to do that will you please suggest me anything how to get data from these tables should i write SQL query or any other things actually i'm new to this @JonathanRibas

Comment: Are you using MSI for your stock management?

Comment: Actually my Magento version is Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1 so it is by default enable in Magento 2 @JonathanRibas

Comment: Take a look at `Magento\InventorySalesApi` module.

Comment: How could i get the disabled product i want to use InventorySalesApi Module Query ?or anything else will you please help me to get that @JonathanRibas

Comment: Please add details on your description like products print that are out of stock. We can actually see a quantity but no saleable quantity. What do you want exactly in your filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112146/discussion-between-prits-and-jonathan-ribas).

Comment: Before chat, you need to provide more information for other people being able to help too.

Comment: Actually i want disabled product id's and their price by using productcollection.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below:

```
    $updatedproids = [];
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in'=>array(2)))

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $updatedproids[] = $product->getId();
    }

    print_r($updatedproids);
```

Comment: It gives an empty array @Ritesh